# How to add vibration to cocos2d-x 3.2 on Android and iOS devices?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, android-vibration, iphone-vibrate

I want to vibrate my device in one of my slider functionality, using cocos2d-x 3.2.

I followed some of reference links regarding this on the official [forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/ios-and-android-native-functionality-vibration-and-alert/8237) but I'm still stumped.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Searching a lot , Finally i am done with my Vibrate Function in Cocos2d-x 3.2 for android.

There is one Vibrator Class.

**Vibrator.h**

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#endif
#define  CLASS_NAME "org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper"
class Vibrator
{
public:
static void Vibrate(int time);
static void CancelVibrate();
};
#endif
```

**Vibrator.cpp**

```
#include "Vibrator.h"

void Vibrator::Vibrate(int time)
{
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
JniMethodInfo t;

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, CLASS_NAME, "vibrate", "(I)V"))
{
    t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID, time);
    t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
}
#endif
}
void Vibrator::CancelVibrate()
{ 
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
JniMethodInfo t;
if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, CLASS_NAME, "cancelVibrate", "()V"))
{
    t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
    t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
}
#endif
}
```

=> in AndroidManifest.xml : add below permission .

=> in src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java file : add below 2 methods

first import => import android.os.Vibrator;

then , add these 2 methods

```
public static void vibrate ( int vibrateTime)  {
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) sActivity.getSystemService (Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate (vibrateTime);
}

public  static  void  cancelVibrate () {
    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) sActivity.getSystemService  (Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.cancel ();
}
```

Now, Whenever we want to use Vibrate Function we just have to include this Vibrator Class & Simply Calling it as below .

```
Vibrator::Vibrate(50);
```

For Disabling it,

```
Vibrator::CancelVibrate();
```

in won't work in Tab as it does not having Vibrator in it .

Comment: becuase Tab has no Vibrator in it.

Answer (score 0):

There's supposed to be a working implementation of vibrate on iOS and Android on [FenneX's github](http://%20https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX2).

> The header file is in
>   [Classes/FenneX/NativeWrappers/NativeUtility.h](https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX/blob/master/Classes/FenneX/NativeWrappers/NativeUtility.h).
>
> [iOS implementation is in proj.ios_mac/ios/Misc/NativeUtility.mm](https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX/blob/master/proj.ios_mac/ios/Misc/NativeUtility.mm)
>
> Android implemention have the C++ in
>   [proj.android/jni/NativeUtility.cpp](https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX/blob/master/proj.android/jni/NativeUtility.cpp)
>
> the Java [somewhere in the src](https://github.com/FenneX/FenneX/blob/master/proj.android/src/com/fennex/modules/NativeUtility.java).

sourced from a [forum post](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-make-the-android-mobile-vibrate-in-cocos-3-0/12175/3) asking the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code found in the [forum post](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-make-the-android-mobile-vibrate-in-cocos-3-0/12175/3):

- you need to add a header in your `Classes/` folder where you just have the cpp function declared but not defined.
- you need to add a function definition in the `proj.android/jni`, in a `.cpp` file. I used `proj.android/jni/hellocpp/main.cpp`, which I believe is the default for a starter cocos2dxv3 project. In this method you call the method you've defined in your java, in this case it was defined as a static method on your Activity. The default was named `AppActivity.
- make sure you've got the vibration permission on your `proj.android/AndroidManifest.xml`, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

So, in one of your standard C++ headers in the `Classes/` folder, add

```
//Classes/any_header.h
void vibrate(int milliseconds);
```

and in the associated `.cpp` file, call it:

```
//Classes/any_header.cpp
void get_hit()
{
  vibrate(200);
}
```

In your `proj.android/AndroidManifest.xml`, you'll want to add that line

```
<manifest>
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
</manifest>
```

In a cpp file the `jni` will deal with, say `proj.android/jni/hellocpp/main.cpp`, you'll need to define the connection between the Java and C++ by calling the Java method:

```
//proj.android/jni/hellocpp/main.cpp
/* this function should already exist though */
void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
}

/* this is the new one you're adding, where org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity
   is the java file where your Activity with the vibrate static method is defined 
*/
void vibrate(int milliseconds)
{
    JniMethodInfo minfo;
    CCAssert(JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(minfo, "org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity", "vibrate", "(I)V"), "Function doesn't exist");
    minfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(minfo.classID, minfo.methodID, (jint)milliseconds);
    minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(minfo.classID);
}
```

finally, here's the `.java` file where the android call to vibrate is made. Mine was `proj.android/src/org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity.java`

```
/* default imports */
package org.cocos2dx.cpp;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

/* imports needed for vibration stuff */
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {

    private static volatile Cocos2dxActivity mainActivity;    
    public static void setMainActivity(Cocos2dxActivity activity)
    {
        mainActivity = activity;
    }

    public static Cocos2dxActivity getMainActivity()
    {
        if(mainActivity == null)
        {
            Log.w("MY_APP_NAME_GOES_HERE", "Warning : null main Activity");
        }
        return mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppActivity.setMainActivity(this);
    }

    public static void vibrate(int milliseconds)
    {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getMainActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (getMainActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) != null) 
        {
            v.vibrate(milliseconds);
        } 
    }
}
```