# cocos2d-x device vibrate in Lua

Tags: android, c++, lua, cocos2d-x, vibration

I would like some guidelines how to get device vibration working using Lua with cocos2d-x. Initially I would like a solution for Android, but eventually I require an iOS solution as well

I can see a solution here to get the vibration working in C++:

[How to add vibration to cocos2d-x 3.2 on Android and iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018919/how-to-add-vibration-to-cocos2d-x-3-2-on-android-and-ios-devices)

But I am unsure how to incorporate this solution into my Lua project so I can call the vibrate function from Lua.